# ssis bulk insert slow in the server

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package which save the xml into tables, If i run the package in BI studio and connect to my local sqlserver, it runs fast i.e., 10 min.

But if i connect to dev server and run, then it's taking 2 hours. what will be wrong with the server? i checked the *Recovery Model* as well, both are *FULL*. Any suggestion please.

> The only differnce is my machine is sqlserver 2008 R2, but the server
>   is sqlserver 2008. Will this create such a huge difference

Comment: Why are you developing on a differnt version than the dev and or prod servers (which sould be in synch as well?)

Comment: @HLGEM : I am doing a proof of concept, not in prod mode, that's why different versions.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat : If u like to help, do it. otherwise, please don't deviate to enrelated topic.

Comment: @Madhan: Touche. Please upvote and stop wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deploying the package to your dev SSIS server and run from within SQL on the target box.  If you run the package locally, but connect to a remote box, you will have network latency issues passing the data back and forth that may be causing your speed issue.  By having the package and files on one box, you eliminate this possibility.

If the speed does not improve with all items on the same server, try and establish what specific activity causes the difference in time (i.e. is it writing to disk? could there be a difference in the amount of data already in the table / indexes / triggers between the two servers?)

I would be surprised if the version of SQL 2008 is causing the issue.

Comment: you are right the version doesn't make any difference, The problem is with the Rows per batch, i have changed and it's processing it fast

Comment: Answer is changing Rows per batch and Data Access mode to "Fast Load". still marking the above one as answer, Thanks for your time and effort Daryl